# Lag of minutes for poloniex API `returnChartData`?

Tags: api

It seems that Poloniex takes up to 2-3 minutes (with quite a lot of variance) to compile the OHLC data (API method `returnChartData`) of a period that just ended. I've experimented with 30 minutes periods, so 2-3 minutes is up to 10% of a period, which is a lot!

Could it be that I'm doing something wrong? I'm using this [python-poloniex wrapper](https://github.com/s4w3d0ff/python-poloniex), and I'm after the OHLC prices of a few BTC pairs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not doing nothing wrong. It's internal issue of Poloniex.
Every day I see that most of cryptocurrencies have missed candlesticks. And after up to 40 min are updated.
Even on charts you can see that